# How to simulate user input in C#

Tags: c#, location, user-input

How do I set the cursor position in a window of a third party programm (not the screen location, I need it for the window location)?

And how can I paste (Ctrl + V) something to this window?

Comment: Are you trying to do some UI automation testing here?

Comment: You should have a look at [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/), a GUI automation scripting tool

Comment: Thanks, seems to be a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest reading up a bit on Coded User Interface Tests. They are actually fairly easy to implement on a basic level. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much. Didn't thought that it is easy like this.